# is it possible to array push value into existing array value with sum?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

is it possible to array push value into existing array value with sum?

```
$nvArr = Array("1"=> 35, "2"=> 1, "3"=> 2, "8"=> 56, "9"=> 78);
```

I have add one more array value into existing array

```
$nvArr1 = Array("1"=> 35, "2"=> 1);
```

And i want to like following out put

```
$nvArr = Array("1"=> 70, "2"=> 2, "3"=> 2, "8"=> 56, "9"=> 78);
```

Comment: what do you mean by array push

Comment: i have update question please have a look.

Comment: What should happen if a key in `$nvArr1` doesn't exist in `$nvArr`?

Comment: @Jack: same as in reverse direction? would be nice to know the requirement, because current solutions doesn't handle this scenario.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath My answer does handle that scenario, but it's not clear whether that's indeed the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it with foreach

```
foreach($nvArr1 as $key => $val){
  (array_key_exists($key, $invArr))?
    $invArr[$key] += $nvArr1[$key]
    : $invArr[$key] = $nvArr1[$key]
}
```

Comment: How to remove same key value.